# Why Magento has .html suffix?

Tags: url

Why does Magento add a .html suffix on the URLs?

I mean without this suffix it is better for SEO.

Comment: Because it's html output, Magento IDs it as such with a file suffix, suffixes don't really affect anything except cosmetic detail and it's not really worth discussing when you can SO easily change it if your visual preference so requires.

Answer (score 5):

That is the default Magento behaviour, you can change it by going to `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations` and modifying `Product URL Suffix` and `Category URL Suffix` respectively.

The suffix itself has relatively low to no SEO impact.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But the question is more theoretical. I want to know why Magento adds the suffix in the first place.

Comment: Like I've said, with / without suffix doesn't have any SEO impact, the clean URL's were not as common / practiced back when Magento was just released, a lot of  CMS's used to add suffix to pages. There is no special reason for using it, it is a default that was not and probably will not be changed since sites are still using it.

Comment: @KlevisMiho - The SEO mini-wars over what is essentially a cosmetic detail have sparked many a long-winded big-endian, little-endian discussion on various forums. Crack your hard boiled egg by whichever end you so wish and your neighbor can do as he likes. Leave the discussion over in Lilliput where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

Set whatever you want. The configuration screen is here `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimisation`.